# Measurable Function Notation

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

In a book I'm reading, if $f:\Omega\to X$, is a measurable function, the authors write it is $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{B}(X)$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$, and $\mathcal{B}(X)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra over induced by the norm topology on $X$, a linear space.  I presume that this notation, $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{B}(X)$, is used to signify that $f$ is measurable with respect to these two topologies, but it's not explicitly stated in the book, nor is it a notation with which I am familiar.  Does anyone have a reference for this notation?

Comment: The notation $\mathscr{F} / \mathscr{B}(\mathrm{X})$ is used to signify measurability from the measure space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F})$ into the measure space $(\mathrm{X}, \mathscr{B}(\mathrm{X})).$

Comment: Is that well known?

Comment: I know it. I read it many times. How well know? I don't know. They also use (I fancy this one) the notation $(\mathscr{F}, \mathscr{B}(\mathrm{X}))$-measurable.